# Unexpected failure, please try later (in reply to end of DATA command)

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, email-bounces

while trying to send emails to the following address `some_user@f-gs.jazztel.es` i always get the following error message. Could any one tell where can i look in order to find what's going wrong?

This is the log lines generated by postfix:

```
Jul 23 11:42:20 we postfix/smtpd[4998]: connect from we.webeloping.es[127.0.0.1]
Jul 23 11:42:20 we postfix/smtpd[4998]: Anonymous TLS connection established from we.webeloping.es[127.0.0.1]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Jul 23 11:42:20 we postfix/smtpd[4998]: D27DA45639: client=we.webeloping.es[127.0.0.1], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=pau@example.com
Jul 23 11:42:20 we postfix/cleanup[3602]: D27DA45639: message-id=
Jul 23 11:42:20 we opendkim[5352]: D27DA45639: DKIM-Signature field added (s=default, d=example.com)
Jul 23 11:42:20 we postfix/qmgr[5488]: D27DA45639: from=, size=914, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 23 11:42:20 we amavis[28710]: (28710-08) ESMTP::10024 /var/lib/amavis/tmp/amavis-20140723T110050-28710-0MnkZg6B:  ->  SIZE=914 Received: from we.webeloping.es ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (we.webeloping.es [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024) with ESMTP for ; Wed, 23 Jul 2014 11:42:20 +0200 (CEST)
Jul 23 11:42:21 we in.imapproxyd[952]: LOGIN: 'pau@example.com' (127.0.0.1:60966) on existing sd [13]
Jul 23 11:42:21 we amavis[28710]: (28710-08) dkim: VALID Author+Sender+MailFrom signature by d=example.com, From: , a=rsa-sha1, c=relaxed/simple, s=default, i=@example.com, ORIG [127.0.0.1]:53668
Jul 23 11:42:21 we amavis[28710]: (28710-08) Checking: nKdhvt50UqWQ [127.0.0.1]  -> 
Jul 23 11:42:21 we amavis[28710]: (28710-08) p001 1 Content-Type: text/plain, size: 212 B, name: 
Jul 23 11:42:22 we postfix/smtpd[4988]: 6B9D64563A: client=we.webeloping.es[127.0.0.1], orig_queue_id=D27DA45639, orig_client=we.webeloping.es[127.0.0.1]
Jul 23 11:42:22 we postfix/cleanup[3602]: 6B9D64563A: message-id=
Jul 23 11:42:22 we postfix/qmgr[5488]: 6B9D64563A: from=, size=1821, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 23 11:42:22 we amavis[28710]: (28710-08) FWD from  -> ,BODY=7BIT 250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 6B9D64563A
Jul 23 11:42:22 we amavis[28710]: (28710-08) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInternal}, LOCAL [127.0.0.1]:53668 [127.0.0.1]  -> , Queue-ID: D27DA45639, Message-ID: , mail_id: nKdhvt50UqWQ, Hits: -3, size: 1224, queued_as: 6B9D64563A, dkim_sd=default:example.com, 1498 ms
Jul 23 11:42:22 we amavis[28710]: (28710-08) TIMING-SA total 1384 ms - parse: 1.22 (0.1%), extract_message_metadata: 2.5 (0.2%), get_uri_detail_list: 0.70 (0.1%), tests_pri_-1000: 4.9 (0.4%), tests_pri_-950: 1.43 (0.1%), tests_pri_-900: 0.57 (0.0%), tests_pri_-400: 6 (0.4%), check_bayes: 5 (0.4%), b_tokenize: 1.53 (0.1%), b_tok_get_all: 1.19 (0.1%), b_comp_prob: 1.27 (0.1%), b_tok_touch_all: 0.10 (0.0%), b_finish: 0.34 (0.0%), tests_pri_0: 1237 (89.4%), check_spf: 0.18 (0.0%), check_dcc: 116 (8.4%), check_pyzor: 50 (3.6%), check_razor2: 1049 (75.8%), tests_pri_500: 2.8 (0.2%), tests_pri_1000: 28 (2.0%), total_awl: 26 (1.9%), check_awl: 0.12 (0.0%), update_awl: 0.03 (0.0%), learn: 91 (6.6%), b_learn: 89 (6.5%), b_count_change: 4.8 (0.3%), get_report: 0.77 (0.1%)
Jul 23 11:42:22 we postfix/smtp[4982]: D27DA45639: to=, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=1.6, delays=0.14/0/0/1.5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 6B9D64563A)
Jul 23 11:42:22 we postfix/qmgr[5488]: D27DA45639: removed
Jul 23 11:42:22 we amavis[28710]: (28710-08) size: 1224, TIMING [total 1503 ms] - SMTP greeting: 1 (0%)0, SMTP EHLO: 1 (0%)0, SMTP pre-MAIL: 1 (0%)0, SMTP pre-DATA-flush: 1 (0%)0, SMTP DATA: 40 (3%)3, check_init: 0 (0%)3, digest_hdr: 2 (0%)3, digest_body_dkim: 4 (0%)3, mime_decode: 6 (0%)4, get-file-type1: 11 (1%)4, parts_decode: 0 (0%)4, check_header: 1 (0%)4, AV-scan-1: 3 (0%)5, spam-wb-list: 1 (0%)5, SA parse: 2 (0%)5, SA check: 1381 (92%)97, decide_mail_destiny: 4 (0%)97, notif-quar: 0 (0%)97, fwd-connect: 4 (0%)97, fwd-xforward: 1 (0%)97, fwd-mail-pip: 3 (0%)98, fwd-rcpt-pip: 0 (0%)98, fwd-data-chkpnt: 0 (0%)98, write-header: 1 (0%)98, fwd-data-contents: 0 (0%)98, fwd-end-chkpnt: 26 (2%)99, prepare-dsn: 1 (0%)99, main_log_entry: 6 (0%)100, update_snmp: 2 (0%)100, SMTP pre-response: 0 (0%)100, SMTP response: 0 (0%)100, unlink-1-files: 0 (0%)100, rundown: 0 (0%)100
Jul 23 11:42:29 we postfix/smtp[30874]: 6B9D64563A: to=, relay=mail.jazztel.es[62.14.3.193]:25, delay=7.3, delays=0.03/0/5.1/2.2, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host mail.jazztel.es[62.14.3.193] said: 421 Unexpected failure, please try later (in reply to end of DATA command))
Jul 23 11:42:33 we postfix/smtp[26963]: 50A3545590: to=, orig_to=, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[173.194.78.27]:25, delay=24, delays=0.04/0/11/13, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1406108553 bp2si3713715wib.59 - gsmtp)
Jul 23 11:42:33 we postfix/qmgr[5488]: 50A3545590: removed
```

This is the bounce email it generates:

```
: host mail.jazztel.es[62.14.3.193] said: 421 Unexpected
    failure, please try later (in reply to end of DATA command)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; some_user@f-gs.jazztel.es
Original-Recipient: rfc822;some_user@f-gs.jazztel.es
Action: delayed
Status: 4.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mail.jazztel.es
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 421 Unexpected failure, please try later
Will-Retry-Until: Sun, 27 Jul 2014 08:53:45 +0200 (CEST)
```

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Only the operator of the `mail.jazztel.es` can tell you what exactly happens at their end. It should be a transient error.

Answer (score 2):

That's not exactly a bounce message, it's a temporary delivery failure message. The recepient's mail server is telling you that the problem is `421 Unexpected failure, please try later.`. Your mail server says that it will keep trying to send the message until Sunday Jule 27.

The reason for this temporary failure isn't possible for anyone other than the sysadmin of the recipient mail server to figure out. It may be that it's having disk issues, or it may be some greylisting implementation that's set to give this useless message instead of informing you of the problem.

You can contact the sysadmin of the recipient's mail server. Their address **should** be `postmaster@jazztel.es`, but unfortunately many companies don't watch their postmaster address as they should.

Comment: postmaster@jazztel.es does not exists, any alternative?

Comment: Check their website for contact information?

Comment: If they don't have a website with usable contacts, run a `whois` search for the recipient domain, find a contact email address for their NOC, tech support, or admins, and try that.